# python : graphviz not show bigger or smaller mark

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

this problem in below image .
in windows 10 os.
and jupyter notebook.
and version python 3.8.
a create image with graphviz.

[image: graphviz]

In the marked spots in red.
It should show a bigger sign.
code python in jupyter notebook.

```
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus
dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
dtree.fit(X_train,y_train)

dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=dot_data, filled=True, rounded=True, 
special_characters=True, feature_names=X_train.columns)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You did not show your python code, but this works directly in dot:

```
digraph "le" {
  le [label="look &le; here"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solve error . a os is windows. i am try in linux 
install Graivis `sudo apt-get install graphviz`
and not propblem.
but a problem not solve in windows os